# Working with Many to Many relation

Tags: yii2

I have a "article" table and "tag" table and they are joined by a "article_tag" table using many to many relationship.

Implementing in Yii2 is a bit difficult to me. Taking example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418101/yii2-insert-relational-data-with-junction-table-many-many-connection) i am able to save. However it is not very automated, as i have to loop through the tags selected to populate in article_tag. My question more about the "update" part. Updating the records will require me to consider one extra scenerio

if i remove one tag when updating, i have to verify the current data in the database against the newly submitted data and do delete first. I searched answers online to handle this scenerio, however there isnt much info online but simple insert etc.

Anyway Yii2 can handle this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the behavior
https://github.com/voskobovich/ManyToManyBehavior.

Or when you updated your relations of tag then you should delete all relations and just add all new relations.  And use transaction. This is simple way.